# Connecting to a wireless network when you need to accept terms and conditions first

Tags: raspbian, wireless, wifi

I just got my raspberry pi, and I successfully connected to my wireless home network. I am now traveling, and I need to connect to a wireless network, except it requires me to accept terms and conditions before connecting to the network. I tried to use the wifi config tool, but whenever I connect and open my browser, it just says that I'm not connected. Is there a special way I need to handle this? I'm using Raspbian. Thanks for any help.

P.S. There's a blue box saying that my question appears to be subjective and will likely be closed. Why is this?

Comment: [This](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) should explain why the question may be closed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it just was set of by a keyword such as 'need' or 'accept', not an actual fact that it will be closed.